# Moving to center of website (If possible, auto adjusts size on mobile devices)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

sorry for bad english. Any ideas to move this onto the center without using margins etc.? Maybe there are other ways.
[image: img1]

And is it possible for the image and video to auto adjust on any mobile screens? Below the code I used: 
**HTML**

```
<div id="tv_container">
  <iframe width="720" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vToBbWibGw8?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#tv_container {
  width: 720px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}
#tv_container:after { //frame
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: url('../home-img/framevid(4).png') no-repeat top left transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
#tv_container iframe { //video
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: have you looked at flex?

Comment: I haven't tried flexible box before, will try to do this. I think this might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 3 ways to center the image:

1. Set its margin to auto

```css
margin: 0px auto;
```

2. Use grids and use the following code in your CSS:

```css
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  // justify-self: center;
  // justify-items: center;
  // align-items: center;
  // ...
```

3. The way I do not recommend using position hosts is to place one tag as the parent tag with equal or relative position and the other tag (photo) as the child tag and with four main directions of its position Set on the page.

As for the size of the image in different page sizes, I must say that setting the width of the page should not be using pixels and you should use the percentage as follows:

```css
width: 80%;
```

Comment: Will try every single one of them, hoping it works for what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center` to your object style.

I don't know which objects you want to centered but it should works with all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I just added CSS and HTML elements through JS. Here is my code:

```css
#tv_container {
    width: 720px;
    height: 480px;
    position: relative;
}

#tv_container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url('../home-img/framevid(4).png') no-repeat top left transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}

#tv_container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.frame {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="frame">
        <div id="tv_container">
            <iframe width="720" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vToBbWibGw8?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried this, but still having issues. But, will modify some of them to work. Thanks!